# ORACLE DB WITH Microsoft Query - LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ms-query

so I have access to the Oracle DB only via Microsfot Query using preconfigured System DSN and I need to select from it multiple rows of data, which all are distinct only by single column. Tables I refer to looks liek this:

> Tickets
>   ID, time, LastGroup, log
>   1 , 1234, foo, bar
>   2 , 2345, fob, bat
>
> Updates
>   ID, Update
>   1 , foo
>   1 , bar
>   1 , foobar
>   2 , foo
>   2 , bar
>
> Goups
>   ID, Group
>   1 , you
>   1 , me
>   1 , us
>   2 , someone
>   2 , anyone

I'm trying to get data from all 3 tables joining them by ID. Log field is a CLOB type, and IT stores a lot of raw text, to avoid returning it many times i want to merge values form rows which are distinct only by single column, to get something like:

ID, time, log, Updates, Groups
1 , 1234, bar, "foo; bar; foobar", "you; me; as"

To achieve this I tried to use LISTAGG function, but Microsoft Query is giving me an "Didn't expect 'GROUP' after the SELECT column list." error.

LISTAGG part of select looks like this:
    `LISTAGG(Updates.Update, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Updates.Update) "Updates"`

Anyone know if it's even possible to use this feature in MS Query? If so, how? Maybe my aproach is wrong? I will be gratefull for any suggestions.

PS. I'm using oracle 11g driver, so this function should be supported.

Comment: Create a view, then select from the view

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more? I'm not exactly expert on MS Query

Comment: This has nothing to do with MS Query. Create a view using [`create view`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) in Oracle and query that _view_ instead of your table from within MS Query.